# Android + Kotlin: Endless loop when trying to serialise with Gson().toJson ()

Tags: android, json, kotlin, serialization, gson

Given this class:

```
import java.io.Serializable

class AWPainting(
    var id: Int = 0,
    var author: String = "",
    var authorEmail: String = "",
    var url: String = "",
    var filename: String = "",
    var active: Int = 0,
    var thoughtId: Int = 0): Serializable
```

I'm trying to serialize it with Gson library as can be seen in the next extension method:

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>?.saveArrayListInPreferences(key: String) {
    if (this != null) {
        if (this.isNotEmpty()){
            val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                aw.context
            )

            val editor = prefs.edit()
            val gson = Gson()
            val json = gson.toJson(this)
            editor.putString(key, json)
            editor.apply()
        }
    }
}
```

For for an unknown -to me- reason the

```
val json = gson.toJson(this)
```

leads to an endless loop, which in the end leads to an exception, of course.

It was working before, but something I'm not being aware of, might have happened. What can I try next?

Edit 1: StackTrace of the Exception (shortened).

I had to shorten the StackTrace because it exceeds the max amount of characters permitted in a question body.

```
2022-09-05 23:03:57.131 25594-25594/com.artandwords.thoughtoftheday E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1153)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1153)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1153)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1153)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1153)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1153)
2022-09-05 23:03:57.131 25594-25594/com.artandwords.thoughtoftheday E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1153)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1153)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1153)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1153)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1153)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
2022-09-05 23:03:57.131 25594-25594/com.artandwords.thoughtoftheday E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1153)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1153)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1153)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1153)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1153)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
2022-09-05 23:03:57.132 25594-25594/com.artandwords.thoughtoftheday E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Edit 2: State of the arraylist when crashing.

[image]

Edit 3: About ModelMapper.

ModelMapper is an Android library I use to map classes (one class into another).

This is another screenshot of the state of the list, which indeed contains only AWPainting objects.

[image]

ModelMapper initialisation inside class:

```
var modelMapper: ModelMapper = ModelMapper()

init {
    modelMapper.configuration.matchingStrategy = MatchingStrategies.STRICT
}
```

Comment: Is it an infinite loop or infinite recursion (causing a `StackOverflowErrror` eventually)? For the latter, most likely there is a cycle in your data structure, e.g. the list (or one of its elements) contains itself. Could you please include the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Thank for your reply @Marcono1234. I edited and added more information. Let's see if that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the stack trace. I assume there is indeed a cycle in your data structure. Does that list which is causing the `StackOverflowError` only contain `AWPainting` instances? If so, could you please check the properties of that class again. Your screenshot shows that it has a `modelMapper` field which is not mentioned in your question. You will probably have to debug your code (or check the logic again) to find out where there is a cycle.

Comment: Thanks again @Marcono1234. The mapper is a library I use to map classes, but I'm not sure why is being part of the AWPainting fields. Maybe this is because I'm mapping AWPainting to AWPaintingDTO and vice-versa? don't know. The list only contains AWPainting objects, and I edited again to see if it helps you more. It was working not so long ago. The only thing I remember I've. done is to convert AWPainting from an object class to a real class.

Comment: OK @Marcono1234, I've finally found the solution. I'll post it in a moment, so you can forget about my issue, but thank you very much for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution myself. While refactoring I've moved the map method (used to map classes with ModelMapper library) to the AWPainting class (and forgot about that), so the class ended like this:

```
class AWPainting: Serializable {

    var id: Int = 0
    var author: String = ""
    var authorEmail: String = ""
    var url: String = ""
    var filename: String = ""
    var active: Int = 0
    var thoughtId: Int = 0

    private var modelMapper: ModelMapper? = null

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "background" + String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%04d", id)
    }

    fun <D> map(outClass: Class<D>): D {
        return modelMapper!!.map(this, outClass)
    }

    /*
     * Model mapper property setting are specified in the following block.
     * Default property matching strategy is set to Strict see {@link MatchingStrategies}
     * Custom mappings are added using {@link ModelMapper#addMappings(PropertyMap)}
     */
    init {
        modelMapper = ModelMapper()
        modelMapper!!.configuration.matchingStrategy = MatchingStrategies.STRICT
    }
}
```

The modelMapper field itself was causing the recursion (infinite loop), but I've found that if you add the @Transient decorator over a field, ModelMapper will ignore that field when serializing, so the field declaration ends like this:

```
@Transient
private var modelMapper: ModelMapper? = null
```

And this way it's working fine again.

Thanks to me and to @Marcono1234 for the effort :)